# css gradiant background long page

Tags: html, css

I have a a background image on my html with css page, from blue at the top, to white at the bottom.

However, the image 400x800 and the page is much longer, so it repeats.

The page length varies all the time.

Is it possible to solve this so the background stretches to the page length somehow? or maye make it not repeat and make the background white with the image on top?

If yes, how please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is to set the image to not repeat and then set the background color the same as one end of the gradient:

```
body {
    background: white url('yourImage') repeat-x top left;
}
```

Getting a gradient to stretch to fit the window is doable, but is more work and would require some javascript.

Comment: You could also use multiple backgrounds and CSS gradients and avoid using an image altogether (currently limited browser support).

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are jQuery / Javascript methods of accomplishing this:

[Resizable Backgrounds with jQuery](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/)

[Stretch background image - jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/background-image-stretch-gradient-color) - [Demo](http://teryaki.eu/Demos/desktopdesigner/desktopdesigner.html)

but besides resorting to solutions like those - you could:

- Select a pattern for your background that repeats (textures etc.)
- Create a very long background image that could handle most navigation that your page
  would deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to make your gradient the same at both ends with the maximum colour difference at the 50% mark.